# Magento 2 get Product Url in Foreach

Tags: url, magento2.2.2, product-urls

In Magento 2, I trying to get the Product URL using this code `$_product->getProductUrl ()`. But it is having only the first product's url to all the products. How to fix it.

Used the Following Code:

```
$_collection = $this->objectManager->get ( '\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product' )->getCollection ();
 $_collection = $collection->getData();
 foreach ( $_collection as $_product ) {
 $_product = $this->objectManager->get ( 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product' )->load ( $_product['entity_id'] );

      echo $product_url = $_product->getProductUrl ();
}
```

Comment: @PankajPareek, Please check my updated Question.

Comment: Please check my answer @SaravananDS

Comment: please inform me if any query.

Comment: Is it helpful for you or not? @SaravananDS

Answer (score 3):

Use this code :

**=> Using object manager :**

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
    foreach($product as $_product){ 
       echo $_product->getProductUrl();
    }
```

**=> Using Factory Method :**

```
protected $_productcollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ..............
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productcollectionFactory,
        ..............
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        ..............
        $this->_productcollectionFactory = $productcollectionFactory;
        ..............

    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $product_url = [];
        $proColl = $this->_productcollectionFactory->getCollection();
        foreach($proColl as $_product){ 
           $product_url[] = $_product->getProductUrl();
        }
        print_r($product_url);
    }
```

**=> Get url by product Id :**

```
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
) {
  $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Then you load the product based on the product id:

```
public function getProductUrl($productId){
  $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
  return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
}
```

**Note : Don't use object manager directly**

Comment: Thanks @Rohan. I will check with this code. Is possible to use this based on the `product_id`?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

***You can use below code***

```
protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ..............
) {

    ..............
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    ..............
  }

public function execute()
{
    $productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $productRequireData = array();
    foreach($productCollection as $_productCollection)
    {
        $productRequireData[] = array('product_url'=>$_productCollection->getProductUrl(),'id'=>$_productCollection->getId());

    }

    return $productRequireData;
}
```

***Filter the collection as per your requirement.***
***Or you can use custom function to display result into phtml file.***

Answer (score -1):

Using object manager  (But its not recommended )

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load( $id);
 echo $_product->getProductUrl();
```